# Translate identification mark on a Chinese bowl (Characters identified: 景德鎮製)

Tags: translation, character-identification

I am trying to translate the identification mark on a bottom of a Chinese bowl. I am almost positive the right two characters translate to "Jingde" but I can't seem to be able to figure out the left two characters.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Reopened because you did provide some research effort. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

景德鎮製: Made in [Jingdezhen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingdezhen), the ancient porcelain-making center.

Note the traditional writing order, from top to bottom and then from right to left.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.

Just wish it had a company name to try to identify the bowl.

Comment: Now there are too many fake. You can just treat it as 'Made in China' instead, ^_^.

Comment: @DanielYeung Very true, I was curious to learn more about this bowl that I had picked up and was curious if it was old or had any value.  At least it didn't have a little gold sticker saying "Made in China" on it as well.

Comment: Quote:- "Note the traditional writing order, from top to bottom and then from right to left"  This is true for this image only if the photo is rotated clockwise by 90 degrees.